# Would the White House maintain a voice recording of the Presidential telephone calls?

Tags: united-states, president

The "transcript" of the President's call [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/official-readout-president-trump-s-july-25-phone-call-with-ukraine-s-volodymyr-zelensky/4b228f51-17e7-45bc-b16c-3b2643f3fbe0/) carries the notation: "*A Memorandum of a Telephone Conversation.· (TELCON) is not a verbatim transcript of a discussion. The text in this document records the notes and recollections of Situation Room Duty Officers and-NSC policy staff assigned to listen and memorialize the conversation in written form as the conversation takes place*."

Would there be an actual voice recording of presidential calls, that would serve as a the basis of verbatim transcript?

And if not, any reports on why not?

Comment: The question asked two years ago did not provide an answer to the question, so I will ask the question again, and note that the answers previously supplied failed to "fully address the question"